# Ansible Molecule not working. ssh: Could not resolve hostname instance: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ansible, molecule

I am new to using molecule and ansible.  I am trying to follow this guide: https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#getting-started-guide

The problem I have is that when I run ...

```
(venv) [red@mac-laptop.local fake_role]$ molecule test
```

... I get this error ...

```
... lots of output ...
INFO     Running default > prepare
WARNING  Skipping, prepare playbook not configured.
INFO     Running default > converge

PLAY [Converge] ****************************************************************

TASK [Include fake_role] *******************************************************

TASK [fake_role : fake_role | Create /tmp/fake] ********************************
fatal: [instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname instance: nodename nor servname provided, or not known", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
instance                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
... a lot more output ...
```

UPDATE:

The error goes away if I add `instance` to my `/etc/hosts` file like so:

```
(venv) [red@mac-laptop.local fake_role]$ grep instance /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   instance
```

But the `/tmp/fake` dir that my `fake_role` creates gets created on my laptop and not in the docker container molecule is supposed to use.

UPDATE II:

Here is my current `molecule.yml` file.  I had not correctly set up the "platforms" section:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
# platforms:
#   - name: instance
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: docker.io/pycontribs/centos:7
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

But now when I run `molecule test` I get this error:

```
TASK [red.fake_role : fake_role | Create /tmp/fake] ******************
fatal: [instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, 
  "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may 
have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the 
target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in 
ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information 
use -vvv.  Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo 
~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-
1668098032.9524324-2225817-158864423468362 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-
1668098032.9524324-2225817-158864423468362=\"` echo 
~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1668098032.9524324-2225817-158864423468362 
`\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: What does your `molecule.yml` file look like?

Comment: @larsks Thank you for comment.  I didn't think to look at the molecule.yml as I assumed it would be correct as per the documentation I am following.  I have updated my question.

Comment: I have opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393035/molecule-test-seems-to-ignore-ansible-cfgs-remote-tmp-setting. Could you please take a look at that? thanks!